# Import psql file trows "ERROR: role "userabc" does not exist"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I try to load a .psql file into a db locally on mine MAC. I created all the needed roles and I can see the roles via

```
SELECT rolname FROM pg_roles;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it will work when you create the role userabc with superuser rights.